# Expression Blend 4 connecting to a Oracle DB

Tags: silverlight, oracle, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

Is it possible to connect to an Oracle database using Expression Blend 4 in a Silverlight application?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can connect with oracle by wcf service as expression blend is not for connecting with db. it doesn't support normal ADO.NET objects like DataTable, DataSet, DataColumn, Database connection  objects. 
the only way is wcf service

Comment: do you have any tutorial how to do it?

Comment: check this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MySilverlightDataApp.aspx